# How can I render an Amazon States Language json to an image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Let's say I have a json representation of an AWS Step function state machine (Such as the provided example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-amazon-states-language.html ).
This can be visualised as seen on AWS when I check the definition, and can be rendered as well in the VSCode AWS Plugin.
Is there a CLI utility/lib that can take this json and render it as an image on my local machine? I would prefer some solution using bash or python, but anything goes. (I want to include it in a generated documentation )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options:

- AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code uses [this class](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/blob/99ef79bcbd18848273196ec7f69c187359516e99/src/stepFunctions/commands/visualizeStateMachine/aslVisualization.ts) to visualize the Amazon States Language.
- There's an NPM module, [aws-sfn-graph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tshepomgaga/aws-sfn-graph) that can do it.

And, of course, you could build something yourself...

Comment: Thanks!
I know building something custom is always an option, however reinventing the wheel does not always worth it.

Comment: Yeah, definitely -- particularly I you can find something that meets the need. I totally understand, but figured the answer is more 'complete' if I include that. ;)